# SSRS Expression nested iif expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

Hi I´m working in a projcet in SSRS and can't get this right. Maybe you can help me?  So I have a report that looks like this with three different tablix where the middle one calculate the ratio of the other two. My problem is that i can't figure out how to calculate the Diff-column for the ratio rows.  [image]

I solved the ratio rows it like this:

```
 =(Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "123", 
    Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))/(Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "456", Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))
```

The Diff column for the groups 123 and 456 I solved like this:

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!MonthNo.Value = 2018, Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))-(Sum(iif(Fields!MonthNo.Value = Budget, Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))
```

I thought that a combination of the two expressions would solve my problem but I can't really get it right. I've tried something like this, but I just get zeros.

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!MonthNo.Value = "2018",
       (Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "123", Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))/(Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "456", Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0)))), CDec(0)))) 
       -
(Sum(iif(Fields!MonthNo.Value = "Budget",
        (Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "123", Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0))))/(Sum(iif(Fields!OutputType.Value = "456", Fields!Production.Value, CDec(0)))), CDec(0))))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: An unexpected error occured while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: '[BC30311] Value of type Microsoft.Reporting.Services.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: The average expression looks more like a ratio to me (growth 456 vs 123). Also your expressions have nested SUM. Even if they work I would advice against them (they can be simplified)

Comment: Sorry, I mean ratio.

Comment: I don't get that error or any error at all after I shut down and started the program again.